# What upconversion phosphor is this?

Tags: solid-state-physics, photon-emission, fluorescence

Is there a way t know which upconversion phosphor was used to create this? The original flickr image doesn't offer any information. If this is impossible, where can I find any images demonstrating a spesific upconversion phosphor?

[image: Laser Physics Lab Fiber that contains infrared light shines with a blue color in the dark. This process is called upconversion fluorescence. Per Henning/NTNU]

Laser Physics Lab
Fiber that contains infrared light shines with a blue color in the dark. This process is called upconversion fluorescence. Per Henning/NTNU

original: https://www.flickr.com/photos/92416586@N05/12188037864/

Comment: Please post photos (reduced if appropriate) rather than links.   Links tend to disappear.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the profile source for that image on Flickr ?